# sql to produce 1 row for each branch

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

I am developing the following SQL to create a Fixed Asset Reconcilliation report.  Ideally, I am trying to end up with 1 row for each branch with the following fields:

```
(1) Branch
(2) Department
(3) Fixed Asset Account
(4) Fixed Asset Amount 
(5) PS Fixed Asset Amount
(6) Difference between Cols 4 and 5
(7) Accum Depreciation Account
(8) Accum Depreciation Amount
(9) PS Accum Depreciation Amount
(10) Difference between cols 8 and 9
```

SQL returns the data I need but many branches have 2 rows like this:

```
0101  10001010   1501  (blank)   (blank)  (blank)   1601  100.00   101.00   1.00
0101  10001010   1501   250.00   255.00    5.00     1601  blank  blank     blank
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
0101   1001010   1501   250.00   255.00   5.00   1601   100.00    101.00   1.00
```

Here's my current sql:

```
SELECT 
ir.ERAC_BRANCH_LGCY_CD AS Branch,
pdr.Department,

pdr.ACCOUNT_FA AS FA_ACCT,
SUM(pdr.COST) AS FA_AMT,
CASE WHEN pdr.account_fa = pgal.acct_nbr THEN pgal.pstd_ttl_amt END AS PS_FA_AMT,
fa_amt - ps_fa_amt AS FA_DIFF,

pdr.account_ad AS AD_ACCT,
SUM(pdr.depr_ltd) AS AD_AMT,
CASE WHEN pdr.account_ad = pgal.acct_nbr THEN pgal.pstd_ttl_amt  END AS PS_AD_AMT,
ad_amt - ps_ad_amt AS AD_DIFF

FROM PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_GL_ACCT_LDGR PGAL 
    ON pdr.deptid =grp_br_ps_org_id
    AND (pdr.account_fa = pgal.acct_nbr or pdr.account_ad = pgal.acct_nbr)
    AND fiscal_yr_mth_nbr = 201508

INNER JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION IR 
      ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

WHERE pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 8
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'

GROUP BY 1,2,3,5, 7,9

ORDER BY 3,1, 2
```

Comment: I think `GROUP BY 1,2,3,5, 7,9` has no sense. It shoud be field names or calculated functions over fields, but not plain numbers. `group by` acts diferent from `order by` which accepts numbers representing the field list on select.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution to this, Use Aggregate functions `Max()` for each column/fields you suspect that can be null or blank. Aggregate functions ignore NULLs in most SQL engines.

Sample Example

```
select * from tablename

id         col1               col2      col3
---------- ---------- ----------
1         Joey               250.00     255.00
1        (blank)            (blank)    (blank)
```

Use Max()

```
Select id, max(col1),max(col2), max(col3)
FROM tablename
Group by.....

     id         col1               col2      col3
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    1         Joey             250.00        250.00
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe67f/3)

Comment: @Plyush..........Thanks for the feedback.  I appreciate your help.  I'm just beginning to write sql and some of these things are more advanced that my skills are at this time.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer this question.